# Simple way to extract key and values data from nested Json Response

Tags: python, json

Hello everyone here is a snippet of my nested json Response.

https://pastebin.com/qTk21iwX

What I want to accomplished to get all the "Row" data from this json response but I have yet to figure out the correct method of approaching this.

This is  what  I have tried is:

```
 response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, json={"script": sql}, verify=verify).json()
print(response)
responseobject = json.dumps(response)
print(responseobject)

for object in responseobject['Result']['Results']:
    print (object)
```

My output after running this code

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: We can't help without seeing the structure of the JSON response.

Comment: The `.json()` on the end of your request is decoding the JSON string/data from the request from a string into a python object. But then you do `responseobject = json.dumps(response)`, which is taking that python object, and dumping it back into a single big string. You then try to do `responseobject['Result']['Results']`.

Comment: TLDR you don't need `responseobject = json.dumps(response)`, your `requests.get(...` line is already returning a python object (presumably a dict)

Comment: So you should just use `response['Result']['Results']`

Comment: @jarmod here is my structure

Comment: You're calling `.json()`, and then trying to pass that to `json.dumps()`. I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: _What I want to accomplished to get all the "Row" data from this json response but I have yet to figure out the correct method of approaching this._ What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: @amc I corrected the TypeError but what I am struggling with is to extract the key and value from all occurrences of the  "Row" object

Comment: @AMC I have tried printing out `for key, value in response['Result']['Results']:
    print(key, ":", value)` but does not give the desired output. It prints out `Entities: Row` multiple times

Comment: @Xfactor Can you share the output?

Answer (score 0):

```
responseobject = json.dumps(response)
```

Here you are turning the response object into a string. So when you do `responseobject['Result']`, you are indexing a string, not a dictionary.

To fix the problem, just remove `responseobject = json.dumps(response)` and do `response['Result']['Results']` instead of `responseobject['Result']['Results']`.

Comment: Thank you for your response this solution  does help with the error I am getting but it does not answer getting the key and values for rows.

Comment: @Xfactor Your current post does not have enough information for me to answer that question. You need to inspect the shape of the data and figure out what keys access the pieces you want.

Comment: I added my  json in the link above and i want all the keys and values from the row

Comment: @Xfactor `response['Result']['Results']` is a list. You can iterate over it just like you tried in the example and then do whatever you want with each dictionary in the list. I suggest you read about lists and dictionaries in python in order to understand how to use them.